# Build flutter release version for Windows 8

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-windows, flutter-build, flutter-release

I am using a Windows 10 PC and need to create a release version of my flutter application for Windows 8. However, `flutter build windows` builds an executable for the Windows version of the PC, you are using, which would be Windows 10 in my case. Therefore I am clueless, how to create a release version for Windows 8.